# getting my SQL query to be displayed in LINQ form

Tags: mysql, sql, linq

I am very new to writing LINQ statements, and I am struggling to write this simple SQL in  LINQ form.

```
SELECT Type, COUNT(*) as [Total Submissions]
FROM Submission
GROUP BY Type
```

this is my attempt:

```
var query = from s in db.Submission
group s.Type
Type = s.Type
Total = s.Type.Count()
```

This is what my output should be:

```
Type       Count of Type
Book            10
Chapter         15
Journal          8
Conference       4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ syntax:

```
var result = from x in db.Submission
    group x by x.Type into grp
    select new { 
        Type = grp.Key, 
        Count = grp.Count()
    };
```

Using lambda syntax:

```
var result = db.Submission
    .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
    .Select(x => new { 
        Type = x.Key, 
        Count = x.Count()
    });
```